# Show Manipulated time instead of Actual Time

Tags: c#, time

I wanted to show the clock timing different from actual time.

The Timing charts is like this

```
| Actual Time   |   Manipulated Time |
-------------------------------------
8:54            |           8:54
8:55            |           8:55
8:56            |           8:55
8:57            |           8:55
8:58            |           8:56
8:59            |           8:56
9:00            |           8:56
9:01            |           8:57
9:02            |           8:57
9:03            |           8:57
9:04            |           8:58
9:05            |           8:58
9:06            |           8:58
9:07            |           8:59
9:08            |           8:59
9:09            |           8:59
9:10            |           9:00
9:11            |           9:00
9:12            |           9:01
9:13            |           9:01
9:14            |           9:02
9:15            |           9:02
9:16            |           9:03
9:17            |           9:03
9:18            |           9:04
9:19            |           9:04
9:20            |           9:05
9:21            |           9:06
9:22            |           9:07
9:23            |           9:08
9:24            |           9:09
9:25            |           9:10
9:26            |           9:11
9:27            |           9:12
9:28            |           9:13
9:29            |           9:14
9:30            |           9:15
9:31            |           9:17
9:32            |           9:19
9:33            |           9:21
9:34            |           9:23
9:35            |           9:25
9:36            |           9:27
9:37            |           9:29
9:38            |           9:31
9:39            |           9:33
9:40            |           9:35
9:41            |           9:37
9:42            |           9:39
9:43            |           9:41
9:44            |           9:43
9:45            |           9:45
9:46            |           9:46
9:47            |           9:47
9:48            |           9:48
9:49            |           9:49
```

So this is how the clock will look ... when the time is actual time I wanted to show manipulated time. Make the array / list / dictionary of the table I got and show the manipulated time. Which would be a last option to go with.

I wanted to find any logic / loop which might accomplish this task easily. Did any body see any pattern which could be implemented in the loop.

A **little bit of variation** is possible in the timing but the graph / chart should look something like this.

[image: Chart of the Timings]

Comment: I would use the fact that the manipulated time is shaped like a section of a parabola or exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a hard task, man.. It involve multiple parameters to find its pattern.

The best I can come up is to make at least step-by-step formulation like this (the input in the function are `i`, `breaker`, `divisor`, and `interval`, the output is `j`):

```
int i_copy = i, acc_val = 0, leap = divisor * interval;
while (i_copy > leap && divisor > 1) {
    i_copy -= leap;
    acc_val += interval;
    divisor--;
    leap = divisor * interval;              
}
int j = i_copy / divisor + acc_val + Math.Max(i - breaker, 0);
```

This is the more complete code used for my testing:

```
void formula(int i, int breaker = 35, int divisor = 3, int interval = 5) {
    DateTime original = new DateTime(2015, 12, 22, 5, 8, 55);
    DateTime convert = new DateTime(2015, 12, 22, 5, 8, 55);

    int i_copy = i, acc_val = 0, leap = divisor * interval;
    while (i_copy > leap && divisor > 1) {
        i_copy -= leap;
        acc_val += interval;
        divisor--;
        leap = divisor * interval;              
    }
    int j = i_copy / divisor + acc_val + Math.Max(i - breaker, 0);          

    original = original.AddSeconds(i);
    convert = convert.AddSeconds(j);

    //Do the printing here...
}
```

I call it like this,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
    formula(i);
```

And this is the result of using that code:

```
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.324 UTC] 8:55 8:55 i: 0    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 0
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.326 UTC] 8:56 8:55 i: 1    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 0
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.326 UTC] 8:57 8:55 i: 2    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 0
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.327 UTC] 8:58 8:56 i: 3    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 1
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.327 UTC] 8:59 8:56 i: 4    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 1
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.327 UTC] 9:00 8:56 i: 5    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 1
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.327 UTC] 9:01 8:57 i: 6    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 2
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.328 UTC] 9:02 8:57 i: 7    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 2
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.328 UTC] 9:03 8:57 i: 8    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 2
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.328 UTC] 9:04 8:58 i: 9    divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 3
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.328 UTC] 9:05 8:58 i: 10   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 3
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.328 UTC] 9:06 8:58 i: 11   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 3
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.329 UTC] 9:07 8:59 i: 12   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 4
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.329 UTC] 9:08 8:59 i: 13   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 4
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.330 UTC] 9:09 8:59 i: 14   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 4
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.330 UTC] 9:10 9:00 i: 15   divisor: 3  acc_val: 0  j: 5
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.330 UTC] 9:11 9:00 i: 16   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 5
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.330 UTC] 9:12 9:01 i: 17   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 6
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.330 UTC] 9:13 9:01 i: 18   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 6
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.331 UTC] 9:14 9:02 i: 19   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 7
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.331 UTC] 9:15 9:02 i: 20   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 7
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.331 UTC] 9:16 9:03 i: 21   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 8
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.331 UTC] 9:17 9:03 i: 22   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 8
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.331 UTC] 9:18 9:04 i: 23   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 9
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.332 UTC] 9:19 9:04 i: 24   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 9
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.332 UTC] 9:20 9:05 i: 25   divisor: 2  acc_val: 5  j: 10
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.332 UTC] 9:21 9:06 i: 26   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 11
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.332 UTC] 9:22 9:07 i: 27   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 12
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.333 UTC] 9:23 9:08 i: 28   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 13
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.333 UTC] 9:24 9:09 i: 29   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 14
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.333 UTC] 9:25 9:10 i: 30   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 15
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.333 UTC] 9:26 9:11 i: 31   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 16
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.334 UTC] 9:27 9:12 i: 32   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 17
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.334 UTC] 9:28 9:13 i: 33   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 18
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.334 UTC] 9:29 9:14 i: 34   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 19
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.334 UTC] 9:30 9:15 i: 35   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 20
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.334 UTC] 9:31 9:17 i: 36   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 22
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.340 UTC] 9:32 9:19 i: 37   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 24
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.342 UTC] 9:33 9:21 i: 38   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 26
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.343 UTC] 9:34 9:23 i: 39   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 28
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.344 UTC] 9:35 9:25 i: 40   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 30
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.344 UTC] 9:36 9:27 i: 41   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 32
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.345 UTC] 9:37 9:29 i: 42   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 34
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.345 UTC] 9:38 9:31 i: 43   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 36
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.346 UTC] 9:39 9:33 i: 44   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 38
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.346 UTC] 9:40 9:35 i: 45   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 40
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.347 UTC] 9:41 9:37 i: 46   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 42
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.348 UTC] 9:42 9:39 i: 47   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 44
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.351 UTC] 9:43 9:41 i: 48   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 46
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.351 UTC] 9:44 9:43 i: 49   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 48
[2015-12-22 07:58:43.352 UTC] 9:45 9:45 i: 50   divisor: 1  acc_val: 10 j: 50
```

Comment: Mind blowing @ian :) Will soon implement and mark as answer if it works

Comment: Yeah, please see... Some parameters like divisor, interval, etc must be adjusted according to your need though. What I put there is just following your example (divisor = 3, interval = 5)

Comment: Code simplified. I just realized that some things can be removed.

Comment: O, great! This means that the code works. And I have just become an established user. =) thanks to you!